# Presenting a modal view controller from OpenURL

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, url-scheme

I am implementing a custom URL scheme in my application and can successfully launch the application from another, and display an alert.

Instead, I would like to present a modal view controller.

From the APPDelegate, how can I display a modal view controller in openURL? Given that the application may be already running, and in a variety of states? For example, what if a modal controller is already being displayed at the time that the URL is sent in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have access to the root view controller from the app delegate. This is done through `self.window.rootViewController` I will use this then to show a modal view controller by invoking the `presentViewController` method.

**EDIT**
To check if your popover is visible and dismiss it you can do something along those lines:

```
if([yourAppDelegate.yourPopover isPopoverVisible]) 
{ 
     [yourAppDelegate.yourPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: And what if a modal controller is already being displayed? The new modal will not present itself.